# Putting this CSS animation when hover on the whole column

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to customize [this template](http://www.templatemonsterpreview.com/66265.html)
Support has not been really useful. I can't post images so I replaced those links with "xxx"

On the section course categories there is some columns.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 teaser_border teaser_border_column_11">
        <div class="teaser text-center  h5">
                <div class="teaser_image">
            <img src="xxx">
        </div>
                    <h5>
                    <a href="rainbow-colleges/course-category/creative-arts/">
                Creative ARts &amp; Media                   </a>
                </h5>
                    <p>
            Explore film, journalism, photography or theatre, music. Learn from the experts
 in creative arts and media...      </p>
                    </div>

        </div>
```

So let's say I want the whole column to hover when the cursor is on and I also want put a link on the img. which hovers too

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 teaser_border teaser_border_column_11">
        <div class="teaser text-center  h5">


<div class="teaser_image"><a href="http://rainbow-colleges/course-category/creative-arts/">
        <img src="xxx">
    </div>
                <h5>
                <a href="http://rainbow-colleges/course-category/creative-arts/">
            Creative ARts &amp; Media                   </a>
            </h5>
                <p>
        Explore film, journalism, photography or theatre, music. Learn 
        from the experts
         in creative arts and media...      </p>
                </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-4:hover {

opacity:0.7;

}



.col-md-4:hover a {

color:#34c663;

transition:0,000002s;

}
```

But how do I make sure the image with the link doesn't hover twice (with the colum hover and img hover)

Also I found the code of the underline but i'm not sure how to put it to show when the hover is on the whole colum or when you put the cursor or the image:

```
.teaser h2 a:after, .teaser h3 a:after, .teaser h4 a:after, .teaser h5 a:after {
    background-color: #34c663;
    content: '';
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: width .3s;
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: After is a pseudo-element not a pseudo-selector, you need to use ::after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I received this answer in another forum and it worked pretty well, I think the part of webkit transition was what was lacking because with this code it worked.

```
.col-md-4 a:hover .teaser_image,
.col-md-4 a:hover p {
    opacity: .7;
}
.col-md-4:hover h5{
    color: #34c663;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
}
.col-md-4 h5:after{
    background-color: #34c663;
    bottom: -5px;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
    width: 0;
}
.col-md-4:hover h5:after {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code there is nothing which hovers twice, there are just 2 different hover effects.

Your column hover will be activated as long you are in the area of the column so it will always be on, if you want to deactivate it you have to nullify it with another hover...

Sample Code:

```css
.col-md-4{
    /* The background-color just to show you the area of the box */
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    .col-md-4:hover a{
    /* Your link tag will be red if your cursor is in the .col-md-4 class */
     background-color: red;
    }
    .col-md-4 a:hover{
    /* Your link tag will get back to normal/nullified if your cursor is on a link tag */
     background-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 teaser_border teaser_border_column_11">
        <div class="teaser text-center  h5">
                <div class="teaser_image">
            <img src="xxx">
        </div>
                    <h5>
                    <a href="rainbow-colleges/course-category/creative-arts/">
                Creative ARts &amp; Media                   </a>
                </h5>
                    <p>
            Explore film, journalism, photography or theatre, music. Learn from the experts
 in creative arts and media...      </p>
                    </div>

        </div>
```

This is how you can show your Hover Effect (Underline) when your cursor is in the column:

```
.col-md-4:hover .teaser h2 a:after, 
.col-md-4:hover .teaser h3 a:after, 
.col-md-4:hover .teaser h4 a:after, 
.col-md-4:hover .teaser h5 a:after {
        background-color: #34c663;
        content: '';
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -5px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: width .3s;
        width: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. What I meant is that the theme by default has images hover when there is a link, so if I put the cursor on the column it hovers and then I move to the img it hovers again. Still the most important thing for me is to make the underline appear when I put the cursor in the hover. I tried this code but it didn't work.. for some reason it makes the underline disappears completely.

Comment: For the underline you can also use text-decoration: underline on your element which should have an underline (.col-md-4:hover h5 a{text-decoration: underline;}

Comment: I looked again, and it couldnt work because  I copied the code you provided, there are 2 things we need to fix: Set the width of the a:after to 100% or remove it. And you need to give your headlines (h2,h3,h4,h5) 'position: relative;'

Comment: Hey dude sorry for answering late the website was down yesterday and I couldn't try. I tried it today though putting 100% in a:after and it still didn't work, but I received an answer on other forum with almost the same you said with a couple of extra lines that made the difference.